# npm stops working after install of discord.js

Tags: node.js, npm, discord.js

I am using NodeJS v8.9.4, on a Windows 10

I was trying to create a discord bot, so I installed discord.js

```
npm install discord.js
```

But then it gave me an error that said that `makedirs` was not allowed.

So I fixed the problem by running command prompt as admin.

(*This mistake is here in case it is related to the problem at hand*)

Then later, running the js source file, I get the error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'discord.js'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
at Module.require (module.js:587:17)
at require (internal/module.js:11:18)
at Object.<anonymous> (filepath)
at Module._compile (module.js:643:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:654:10)
at Module.load (module.js:556:32)
at tryModuleLoad (module.js:499:12)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:491:3)
```

Then I tried reinstalling discord.js, when I find that all npm commands result in

```
module.js:540
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-
cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
module.js:540
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-
cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:538:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:468:25)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:684:10)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:187:16)
    at bootstrap_node.js:608:3
```

Any commands will return the errors above, regardless of what it is. I tried restarting the computer, but it did not work.

Can anyone help me?

All the SO questions I found were either using MacOS solutions or just completely uninstalling npm or NodeJS. I want to avoid any uninstallation unless it is necessary.

Comment: not sure how installing the discord package locally would have that affect, not sure how you will fix this without reinstalling npm

Comment: I have a feeling in your UserName/ folder. You have a node_modules folder with discord.js installed.

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
npm install discord.js --save
```